# Is it possible to change Android emulator fonts?

Tags: android, localization, fonts, emulation

I need to change installed on Android emulator fonts. E.g. I would like to install TrueType font which covers some other locales like Arabic, Chinese or so. I just wonder is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should overwrite `/system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf` using adb or another tool. Make sure to have a backup of the file first.

Comment: I tried to push the `.ttf` font-file on the path that you specified above. But its giving me the following error : `Failed to push selection: Read-only file system`