# In which android version the cursive font is available?

Tags: android, font-family

In my Android app i set the style of my TextView like this:

```
<TextView
            android:fontFamily="cursive" 
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" 
            ...
/>
```

**For example in Lollipop will work because there is the cursive font by default:**
[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29533686/3893550)

Now I'd like to know in which version there isn't the cursive font.

p.s.

> cursive font=DancingScript-Regular.ttf

Comment: - to add a new font, consider going [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487976/what-is-the-best-way-of-installing-new-font-to-android-emulator) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154639/is-it-possible-to-change-android-emulator-fonts) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907530/installing-a-new-font-in-android-emulator)

Comment: Is okay if don't work on emulators, I just want be sure that will work on all physical devices... and so is just an emulators limit.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384114/what-fonts-are-installed-by-default-on-android)

Comment: Cursive is not included in android by default, You can just add it in your assets folder

Comment: Yea i can use this solution for the version where there isn't the cursive font but i'd like to know in which version there isn't this font. I updated my answer with more info.

Comment: Isn't it called `italics`?

Comment: no... fontFamily="cursive" and the ttf file is called DancingScript-Regular.ttf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's weird. The `cursive` font family is officially available starting at API level 16 (Jellybean). However, it uses the `DroidSerif` font which is *not* a cursive looking font.  By API 21, they move to the `DancingScript` font which looks far more cursive like.

So, you may be able to use the keyword in API 16-20, but it won't amount to much.  From API levels 21+, it should look very much like cursive script.

You can look at the available fonts if you go here:

`{ANDROID-SDK-HOME}/platforms/android-{SDK-INT}/data/fonts`

The containing `system-fonts.xml` has all them listed with the corresponding fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `cursive` font family shouldn't be available form android device. Over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13329907/3612065) you can find perfect explanation what you can set using `fontFamily` and `textStyle`.

If you want to use custom fonts I strongly recommend [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) lib.