# fontFamily cursive not working on my phone

Tags: android, textview

This is my xml:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/bus_title"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:fontFamily="cursive"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>
```

When I run the application on my Huawei P20 Lite with Android v9, the cursive font specified in android:fontFamily="cursive" does not display; I just get a standard text style.

Is there some setting on the phone that overrides this, or what else may be the problem? As far as I know the API level should definitely be high enough.

Comment: Try this question similar to your one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588559/in-which-android-version-the-cursive-font-is-available

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have fonts in fonts folder and call it using

- android:fontFamily="@font/your_font"